# SQL Union two tables and keep table name in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, insert-into

I am trying to UNION two tables whilst retaining information about which table the entry is from.

For example, given this input

```
Table A
Column1   Column2
   0         X
   1         Y

Table B
Column1   Column2
   3         Z
   1         Y
```

I want to end up with this:

```
Table C
Column1   Column2 Column3
   0         X        A
   1         Y        A
   3         Z        B
```

I tried an INSERT INTO statement but I can't insert different text in Column3 without getting all the duplicates from e.g. Table 2

Comment: Why (1, Y, A) and not (1, Y, B)? What if table B has (2, Y) instead of (1, Y)?

Comment: I want to keep the first instance of when a specific combination (e.g. 1 Y) appears and the name of the table. I don't want to keep track of duplicates.

Comment: First? Does that mean table A? Or lowest Column 1 value?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain it very well...the table name where the specific combination appears. In this case, table A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `full outer join` :

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.col1, b.col1), COALESCE(a.col2, b.col2), 
       (CASE WHEN a.col1 IS NOT NULL 
             THEN 'A' 
             ELSE 'B' 
        END)
FROM tableA a FULL OUTER JOIN
     tableB b
     ON b.col1 = a.col1;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use window function `row_number()`

```
with cte as
(
select column1,column2,'A' as column3 from tableA
union all
select column1,column2,'B' as column3 from tableB
) , cte2 as
(
select * , row_number() over(partition by column1,column2 order by column3 ) rn
from cte
) select column1,column2,column3 from cte2 where rn=1
```

[demo link](https://rextester.com/VCL1449)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could be the solution you seek.

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, 'A' AS Column3
FROM [Table A]
UNION
SELECT Column1, Column2, 'B' AS Column3
FROM (
    SELECT Column1, Column2 
    FROM [Table B]
        EXCEPT
    SELECT Column1, Column2 
    FROM [Table A]
) b
```

It's strange to me that it doesn't work. Your requirements can be translated as:

1. Take all rows from set **A** and add column with value A.
2. Take all rows from set **B** which are not in set **A** and and add
   column with value B.
3. Return both results from step **1** and **2**.

And this is what this query is doing.

Comment: I've tried that but because column 3 is different the UNION doesn't get rid of the duplicates :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `UNION` combine `tableA` and `tableB` then use `outer join` with `CASE WHEN` to make it.

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT Column1,Column2
  FROM TableA
  UNION 
  SELECT Column1,Column2
  FROM TableB
)
SELECT t1.*,(case when t2.COLUMN1 is NOT null THEN 'A' ELSE 'B' END) Column3
FROM CTE t1 
LEFT JOIN  TableA  t2 on t1.COLUMN1 = t2.COLUMN1 and t1.COLUMN2 = t2.COLUMN2
```

[sqlfiddle](https://rextester.com/WTVU83302)

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
0       X       A
1       Y       A
3       Z       B
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want rows from `a` and then *other* rows from `b`.  This is not exactly a union.

I would approach this as:

```
select a.column1, a.column2, 'a' as column3
from a
union all
select b.column1, b.column2, 'b' as column3
from b
where not exists (select 1 from a where a.column1 = b.column1);
```